# How to create a duration vector from a dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to create a vector of duration from a dataframe. The fata frame includes several behavior and the times at which those start and end. The idea is to fill the vector with duration of each behavior, without considering the type of behavior.

eg: Original dataframe

```
Time    Subject  Behavior  Status
11.901  M        FOR       START
20.896  M        FOR       STOP
20.897  M        NI        START
22.646  M        NI        STOP
22.647  M        FOR       START
26.898  M        TSp       POINT
29.146  M        FOR       STOP
29.147  M        NI        START
30.646  M        NI        STOP
30.647  M        FOR       START
32.148  M        TSp       POINT
39.397  M        FOR       STOP
39.398  M        NI        START
43.647  M        NI        STOP
43.648  M        FOR       START
48.647  M        FOR       STOP
48.648  M        NI        START
51.147  M        NI        STOP
51.148  M        FOR       START
52.088  M        TSp       POINT
54.585  M        FOR       STOP
54.586  M        NI        START
61.334  M        NI        STOP
61.335  M        FOR       START
65.084  M        FOR       STOP
65.085  M        NI        START
66.878  M        NI        STOP
```

=> what I want:
duration: (8.995, 1.749, 4,251, 1, 1.248, ....)

The problems I face: Distinguishing and pairing the starts and ends of differents behaviors in the code. Also, behaviors having "point' in the "status" row is hard to include as there is no duration we can calculate from the dataframe. I would like to consider as 1sec, but so It means that this:

```
22.647  M    FOR       START     
26.898  M    TSp       POINT  
29.146  M    FOR       STOP
```

should be transformed in this:

```
22.647  M       FOR      START
26.897  M       FOR      STOP
26.898  M       TSp      START 
27.898  M       TSp      STOP
27.899  M       FOR      START
29.146  M       FOR      STOP
```

That is what I calculated in the example.

This is really annoying because I have other "point event behavior" and if we need to transform everything it will be a mess. If we cannot add this quite easily, I prefer that we do not consider as a proper duration but I still need that this appear in the duration vector.

Thank in advance for your help, I am still not good at understanding how to talk to R..

Comment: When there is a `"POINT"`, why not compute `STOP - START` and then subtract 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following code is what the question asks for.
It first creates a dataframe with the `Status == 'POINT'` removed according to the rules in the question. Then calls another function to compute the durations vector.

```
removePOINT <- function(DF){
  while(any(DF[['Status']] == 'POINT')){
    n <- nrow(DF)
    i <- min(which(DF[['Status']] == 'POINT'))
    Tm <- DF[i, 'Time']
    Time <- c(Tm - 0.001, Tm, Tm + 1, Tm + 1.001)
    Subject <- rep(DF[i, 'Subject'], 4)
    Behavior <- rep(DF[i, 'Behavior'], 4)
    Status <- rep(c('STOP', 'START'), 2)
    tmp <- data.frame(Time, Subject, Behavior, Status)
    DF <- rbind(DF[1:(i - 1), ], tmp, DF[(i + 1): n, ])
  }
  DF
}
computeDuration <- function(DF){
  grp <- cumsum(DF[['Status']] == "START")
  agg <- aggregate(Time ~ grp, DF, function(x) {
    duration <- x[length(x)] - x[1]
  })
  subtr <- tapply(grp, grp, function(x) if(length(x) > 2) -1 else 0)
  agg[['Time']] <- agg[['Time']] + subtr
  agg[['Time']]
}

df2 <- removePOINT(df1)
computeDuration(df2)
# [1] 8.995 1.749 4.250 1.000 1.247 1.499 1.500 1.000 6.248 4.249 4.999
#[12] 2.499 0.939 1.000 1.496 6.748 3.749 1.793
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(df2)
```

Comment: It is working very well !! So now with this output, how could we indicate which duration is for which behaviour ? In a dataframe of whatever. As the idea is to have this vector or table for 2 individuals and then to compare how they behave.

Comment: @SmartFish Do you want duration per `Behavior` or per `Subject`?

Comment: both ^^ like for each duration we calculated, the behaviour for each subject